# 'Invalid utf8 character string' warning when importing into AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to migrate osTicket from physical Windows machine to AWS RDS, and I get a bunch of warnings while doing so. I am quite a DB noob, so I am not sure what is the issue.

**Source:** Windows, MySQL 5.6.10, backup created with **mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 osTicket > file.sql**

```
mysql> show variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                             |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
| character_set_client     | cp850                                             |                                            
| character_set_connection | cp850                                             |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                            |
| character_set_results    | cp850                                             |  
| character_set_server     | utf8                                              |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                              |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\char|
|sets\                                                                         |
```

**Destination:** AWS RDS, MySQL 5.6.27-log, import with **mysql> source file.sql**. I've created a custom **Parameter Group** to change **character_set_database** to **utf8** since default on RDS is **latin1**

```
mysql> show variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                             |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
| character_set_client     | cp850                                             |                                            
| character_set_connection | cp850                                             |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                            |
| character_set_results    | cp850                                             |  
| character_set_server     | utf8                                              |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                              |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.27.R1/share/charsets/         |
```

I get warnings like these:

```
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF'
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF'
Query OK, 6 rows affected, 6 warnings (0.06 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 6

Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF'
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF'
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF'
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'E2E3CF'
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'D0CF11'
Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'E2E3CF'
Query OK, 20 rows affected, 20 warnings (0.06 sec)
Records: 20  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 20
```

I tried to **set character_set_client=cp850** and the same for **set_connection** and **set_results** before import, but didn't help me.

If anyone could be so kind to help me what I am doing wrong here, it would be really great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many things could have gone wrong with charsets, we need more details.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  All parameters (except pwd) on mysqldump.  Character-related settings in my.cnf.  Proof of what format the source is in -- HEX if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rick. As I said, I am quite a noob with DBs, so probably I won't be able to answer your questions. For **my.ini**, it just has for the characters:
`[mysqld]`
`default-character-set=utf8`

If by `SHOW CREATE TABLE` you mean what's the table charset when the mysqldump is creating them, it's the same for all of them, `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: Also, I've run `mysqldump` with the default options, I've mentioned it in the first post, and what I noticed that all the errors I get, are in `ost_file_chunk` table which is actually storing the file attachments for **osTicket** . As well, that table is around 3.3 GB out of my 3.5 GB dump, and it's practically giving warning for every row which is definining a file chunk (columns are **file_id**, **file_chunk** which is saying hiow much chunks file says, and **data** which is storing blob)

Comment: What is `file_chunk`?  Is some column a `BLOB`?  Are you using the option to dump as hex?  How big is the blob?  How many rows?

Comment: Yes, in `ost_file_chunk` table, third column is `blob`. I was using default dump options, entire table is 3.5 GB large (stores all the attachments for `osTicket`) with 10801 rows. Thanks for the help Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your initial post, where you said you used default options for `mysqldump`, it means you didn't use the `--hex-blob` option. I've played around with osTicket some time ago, and you should definitely used --hex-blob option to create your dump. It will give you much bigger .sql file (and of course, the import to RDS will take more time) but in that way you won't get the UTF8 warnings you're getting now, and your attachments will be available once you deploy osTicket to new host.

One more advice, update to newer versions (1.9 or 1.10) and move those files out of DB, you can use S3 or even EFS now, or just store it under your EBS volume

Comment: thanks. Can you explain more why BINARY, VARBINARY, the BLOB types, and BIT need the `--hex-blob` option? Why `Invalid utf8 character string` without this option?